# UICollectionView.scrollToItem set animation speed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

When using `collectionView.scrollToItem` with `IndexPath`. is it possible to set custom scroll speed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: { [weak self] in
    self?.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 10, section: 10), at: .middle, animated: false)
})
```

Comment: I get a weird effect when doing this. If the animation is too quick, the section or row isn't loaded yet so it's white blank for a split second.

Comment: Just a reminder for other folks. Don't forget to set the animated value as false in scrollToItem(at:) call.
Otherwise, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Use .layoutIfNeeded() on the collectionView to prevent the white flashing.

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 10, section: 10), at: .middle, animated: false)
        self?.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
 })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Why `layoutIfNeeded()` required?